# How do I remove the "nativeHeaders" warning with Spring Integration AWS SNS?

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

In an out-of-the-box configuration of the Spring Integration AWS `SnsMessageHandler` outgoing channel adapter, a Spring `Message` header named `nativeHeaders` of type `LinkedMultiValueMap` is populated somewhere along the chain. During the conversion process to an SNS message, the handler delegates to the `SqsHeaderMapper`, which issues a log at `WARN` level for every message that the automatically-populated `nativeHeaders` can't be converted to an AWS-compatible format.

I don't want to suppress logs from the `SqsHeaderMapper` in case there's a real bug (like I forget to stringify some POJO header value), but I don't see either a flag to prevent creation of the `nativeHeaders` header or a way to configure the `SqsHeaderMapper` instance that's privately owned by the `SnsMessageHandler`. Is there a clean way to remove this warning?

Answer (score 0):

The `nativeHeaders` is populated by the `NativeMessageHeaderAccessor`. I believe this is the part of SNS consumer and its handler. Or SQS. Then it looks like you propagate the message downstream to SNS. And you probably you really mean a `SnsHeaderMapper` in the `SnsMessageHandler`.

I don't think it is really a header mapper responsibility to prevent such a warn for specific headers. It cannot know what is intentional and what is not. Likely now you have a warn, so you are good to use a `HeaderFilter` before `SnsMessageHandler` to remove  those headers which cannot be mapped to SNS attributes.

And sure! You can inject a custom `SnsHeaderMapper` with any desired logic overridden.